# Reading spreadsheet from Jedis and loading them to Redis

Tags: redis, jedis

I am new to this REDIS database and I am trying to use Jedis (by popularity)...
My requirement is to read a spreadsheet of data and load them on REDIS using Jedis (java client for redis).

I can read and get the spreadsheet data in java ( I can use jxl or some other libraries).

I can load the data as regular key values (individual cell contents)... I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Or can I load the entire spreadsheet data into REDIS using Jedis? if yes, how? any pointers would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Redis is a data store and you can use Jedis (or any other client) to read and write data from and to it. You code, for example, could serialize the entire spreadsheet and store it in a single key. Or it could store each in a separate key. Or combinations of these. The real question is what's the data and what you want to do with it. Depending on that, you'll need to figure out how to store in Redis (or any other database) so you use it for your requirements. Put differently - please rephrase your question.

Comment: @Itamar Haber, thank you! I understand my question was little vague because I was clueless in 'how to' ... I am reading and practicing REDIS commands now. Hoping to understand more about them before worrying about clients.

Comment: @Itamar Haber, how could I store "key, [key, value]" object? and need to retrieve by "key.key" to get the value. Like Map<key, Map>

Comment: Redis Hashes are exactly that - look into the hset and hget commands to get started.